# Pymongo date query in "DD/MM/YYYY" format

Tags: python, django, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I've got a mongodb collection with one of the fields like:

```
u'Date': u'15/03/2016'
```

Now from my understanding `u` means that strings are simply unicode which is fine. I'm using Django and pymongo to allow users to select 2 dates and query my DB for stuff between those two dates like that:

```
number = coll.find({"Date": {'$gt': startDate}, "Date": {'$lt': endDate}}).count()
```

Where my startDate and endDate are both in formats "DD/MM/YYYY". What I receive back however is some rubbish data. How to correctly query for dates in python-mongo?

P.S From my understanding comma between those two results in 'AND' query right?

Comment: Use dates not strings

Comment: What do you mean dates? I cannot change anything in db, data is provided by external client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates are stored as strings in the DB, then when you use the operator `$gt` or `$lt`, the operation is a string comparison, not a date comparison. Which means that for example: `"15/03/2016 < 16/02/2016"`, because 5 comes before 6 in lexical order.
For the string comparison to work, the dates would need to be stored in a format so that a "smaller" date is always represented as a "smaller" string. For example by using `YYYY/MM/DD`.

So if you don't want to do the comparison in python, you could either change the date format, or store the date as a date in DB. But in both cases, this means changing the DB...

If doing in Python is OK, then you can do it like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
start_date = datetime.strptime(startDate, date_format)
end_date = datetime.strptime(endDate, date_format)
items = coll.find({})

def compare(c, item):
    item_date = datetime.strptime(item['Date'], date_format)
    if start_date < item_date < end_date:
        return c+1
    else:
        return c

count = reduce(compare, items, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly I cannot change the database, I cannot think about easy way of querying it in python as well.. ;/

Comment: @PawełLaskowski, actually I just thought you may have a better solution: you can use the [map_reduce engine](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) to do the comparison in a javascript function run by the DB. But his goes beyond my current knowledge of mongodb.

Comment: @PawełLaskowski, didn't notice you also had trouble to do it in python, edited my answer with a suggestion :)